# Angular 8 | Dynamic keydown binding in template

Tags: angular, events, dynamic, keydown

### Background

My template generates a sequence of buttons which are numbered by an index from `0 to 9`.

Each button has to listen to a unique and numeric `(keydown.[0...9])` event.

### Problem

This works of course:

```html
<button
  (document:keydown.0)="doSomething(event)"`>
  bla
</button>
```

This does not, trying to specify the keydown event using an index:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let elem of elems; index as index;">

  <button
    (document:keydown[index])="doSomething(event)"`>
    bla
  </button>

</ng-container>
```

### Question

How to dynamically bind an event-listener in an Angular 8 template?

I would prefer not to use a generic `@HostListener` event-listener as a generic method or use any other workaround.

I also tried variations of the above syntax, trying specify the concrete number-key, but no joy.

Comment: Why not to pass index to doSomething function which will handle all of keydown events?

Comment: Sure, but as I stated I would like to avoid any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I missing something, but, for me, has no sense use (document:keydown.0) in a button. A button you use (click). You can use renderer2 to control keyboard keys like

```
  constructor(private renderer:Renderer2,
  @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document){}
      ngOnInit()
      {
        for (let i=0;i<=9;i++)
         this.renderer.listen(this.document, 'keydown.'+i, this.handler)
      }
      handler = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log(e,e.keyCode,e.key);
      };
```

Or fromEvent 'rxjs/operator'

```
   fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(filter(
       (e:KeyboardEvent)=>e.keyCode>=48 && 
                                e.keyCode<=57))
       .subscribe((res:KeyboardEvent)=>{
           console.log(res,res.key)
        })
```

BTW, take a look to this [article from Netanel Basasl](https://netbasal.com/diy-keyboard-shortcuts-in-your-angular-application-4704734547a2)